# How can I serve images from an external server with a percentage width? (PHP)

Tags: php, html, css, image, responsive-design

We currently use another server (well, the same server but different account and domain) to serve images for our website.

It currently works like this:

```
http://images.example.com?src=imagepath&w=300&h=500&q=75.
```

This does automatic image resizing based on the `w=300` and `h=400` that we provide to the URL (pixels).

However, the site is for a car dealership and we don't always want to specify the width. Sometimes we need percentage widths, as the site is responsive, and also, not all images are the same size to begin with, so it leads to distortion if we say all images are 700 wide.

Is it possible to have this kind of image resizing external server but using percentages?

We use Apache, `PHP` and the images are accessed via directory names based on criteria in the database for that car, so for example `images/ford/focus/AA136YH/image1.jpg`.

**TL/DR Question:** How can we serve images from external `PHP` server with percentage widths instead of specifying fixed width and/or height?

Comment: The server which does the resizing has no clue of the size of which it is asked to use a percentage. I.e., "percentage" only has a meaning on the client side browser, "50%" doesn't mean anything to the image serving server. *50% of what?!*

Comment: Is there a common method that people workaround this issue? We seem a bit stuck on how to improve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest CSS like the other answers; if you don't want this, use GD Lib but keep in mind this will use some CPU resources everytime the image is requested.

If you can't use CSS, use a script like the below **but cache the scaled image,** using Memcached for example or disc storage.

GD Lib resizing:

```
<?php
$filename = $_GET['src'];
$percent  = intval($_GET['q']) / 100;

if (!file_exists($filename)) {
    die('image does not exist');
}

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$newWidth  = $width * $percent;
$newHeight = $height * $percent;

$scaled = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

imagecopyresized($scaled, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($scaled);
imagedestroy($scaled);
```

Comment: Thank you for this.. we currently have some similar script to do the resizing, called TimThumb by Ben Gillbanks and Mark Maunder (http://code.google.com/p/timthumb). I'm not sure how good it is, I recently inherited this project, however the issue is we do not wish to serve full size images all the time, as some can be quite large, and we are trying to improve the site speed.

Comment: TimThumb is not good... TimThumb is the #1 vulnerability in all Wordpress hacks ever :) I'd never use it, even if they claim they "fixed" the security issues. The site speed can be tweaked by pre-generating different sizes and caching those.

Comment: Wow - Just shown my manager this as we were not aware of this. Could you point me in the right direction for pre-generating other image sizes, and also, how we determine this in the markup/PHP code? We currently pull in thumbnails around the site, and also on the actual car details page we have the full size images (an image gallery).

Comment: I don't know if they fixed it, but if you google for "thimthumb hack", you'll get what I mean.

Comment: In our online shop, when we put in a new product and it's images, we first generate different sizes of the picture (highres, big, middle, small, thumb). Filename is for example `car-bmw-540i-12345-thumb.jpg` (`<type>-<brand>-<model>-<id>-<pictureType>.jpg`). We save each image filename in the database linked to the product, so we query for the product and get all available images we can display. The images are saved all in the same schema, so you can always access the physical image (without image.php?product=...). This is also faster because you don't need PHP to load the images.

Answer (score 1):

You'd load the image from the server at some pre-determined maximum size and then let CSS do the re-sizing. Your HTML would look like this:

`<img src="http://images.example.com?src=imagepath&w=300&h=500&q=75" class="responsive" />`

And your CSS would look like this:

```
.responsive {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
}
```

This will resize the image to 50% width and set the height according to it's original aspect ratio.

Comment: We currently do this, however we are trying to improve the speed of the site, and loading large versions of all images is slow and causes a lesser ranking in terms of speed.

Answer (score 0):

i would use this css markup for the images

```
img {

width:100%;

}
```

and let the context lead the appropriate sizing of the image. for context i mean the parent `div` containing the image